# I don't understand C++ Primer explanation about virtual destructor

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I don't understand this phrase from the famous C++ Primer :

> "classes used as the root of an inheritance hierarchy almost always
> define a virtual destructor."

I don't understand why the book doesn't say the destructor of a Base class must **always** be virtual.

If it's not and we write this (to use polymorphism) :

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> derived(new Derived);
```

We are sure to have an undefined behaviour.

Sometimes I feel like this book can be really misleading especially for C++ noob like me.

When I first read this book I didn't get Base classes must have a virtual destructor until SonarQube told me during a pull request.

Comment: If the base dtor is not virtual and derived dtor is always called on a Derived* variable, everything is ok, compiler will call Derived dtor. but really, if you need to build a class hierarchy , you should start with a virtual Base dtor

Comment: The rule is that if you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base type and the base type does not have a virtual destructor the behavior is undefined. So if your design uses a base class but does not call for deleting objects of derived types through pointers to that base type then the base type doesn't have to have a virtual destructor. The code is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think it's stupid to count on the fact the undefined behavior may not happen. It's just a bad coding habit to me. It doesn't cost much time to indicate that the base class destructor is virtual. Since there is an inheritance hierarchy the probability a virtual destructor will be needed is high enough to define the destructor virtual even if it doesn't happen to be necessary afterwards.

Comment: @DigitalRomance A class with a virtual dtor (or a virtual function) is not a POD. This can be an issue on some scenario

Answer (score 2):

First, there are environments where you don't do dynamic memory allocation, but still can have class hierarchies, e.g. in embedded systems.

Second, while `std::unique_ptr<>` does not handle the case well, if you only use `std::shared_ptr<>`, then the pattern above will properly delete the object without a virtual destructor. This is because deleter for `std::shared_ptr<>` is captured at construction time (based on the class you specified). You could force the same behavior using a deleter in `std::unique_ptr<>`, but that's reflected in the type.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know std::shared_ptr<> could handle this case well. I've never read that anywhere. I think C++ Primer should have written that a base class destructor should always be virtual to make sure no undefined behavior could happen. Or tell it's not mandatory but explain why it's not. As it is, it's not clear at all.

Comment: @DigitalRomance, std::shared_ptr has a lot of tricks up its sleeve. It’s typical two pointers big, for starters…